# NE5532 strange oscillations

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, oscillation

I am designing a small audio amp and am experiencing some weird oscillations in the first OPamp (NE5532), wich is setup as a noninverting amp. The amp is supplied with +-20V and has 100nf bypass capacitors directly at the supply-pins.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjFxq6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Only the inverting input pins are oscillating at 250kHz with an amplitude of 2V.

The supply is linear regulated (LM317,LM337) and has no measureable noise/ripple.

What could be the reason?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I noticed, that the oscillation is quite intermittent. Then the smallest amount of signal on any pin will retrigger it.

Comment: Could you post your layout please, including info on board stack-up? I suspect this is an usual parasitic feedback effect.

Comment: Is it being driven from a sig gen or is that a simplification?

Comment: **Only inverting input** is oscillating? What about the output pin - is it oscillating at 250 kHz?

Comment: Is it happier if you add an 8k2 resistor from the non inverting input to ground?

Comment: Thats the weird thing. The output pin is not oscillating. But it is also not amplifying the signal properly. The gain is just nearly at unity.

Comment: It is driven with a signal gen with 0.6V rms

Comment: I tired the 8k2. It didnt help

Comment: Measure both In- and Out at the same time. Also note that a capacitive load on In- (like a scope probe) adds some phase shift, reducing the phase margin. You may need compensation in the feedback network to correct for that.

Comment: Are you sure you have your pinout correctly?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried probing both out and in and noticed oscillations on both pins when i probed them. But is this only a matter of phase marigin? The capacitance on the probe should only be about 30pF. With the 10k Resistor, the impact on the system response should be neglegible.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with 10pF-100pF across R1, to reduce the phase shift on the inverting input. Even with 100pF you'll still have fairly flat gain across the audio bandwidth.

And I'd strongly recommend dropping the supply voltage to +/- 15v, for thermal and lifetime reasons if nothing else. +/- 22v is a survival rating, not a recommended rating.

Answer (score 1):

First check that this amp is stable with a gain of 5.7.  Most would be.

Then look carefully at the layout of R1 and R2.

If necessary, add a small cap directly between the output and negative input pins of the opamp.  Since this is audio, you don't care about frequencies above 20 kHz.  I'd set the RC rolloff frequency between this capacitor and R1 at around 40 kHz so that the effect in the desired frequency range is minimal.  With R1 of 47 kΩ, that would be 85 pF, so 100 pF would be fine.  If you change R1, then adjust this cap accordingly.